# Show that the chord of contact of tangents from the point $(a,-a)$ to the parabola $x^2=4ay$ has length $5a$

Tags: parametric

Show that the chord of contact of tangents from the point $(a,-a)$ to the parabola $x^2=4ay$ has length $5a$. My current method uses the distance formula and takes super long, is there some easier method that i'm missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first coordinates of the contact points are easily computed to $x_{1,2}=a\pm a\sqrt5$.  Now the square of the distance of these points is clearly 
$$(x_2-x_1)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4a}(x_2^2-x_1^2)\right)^2.$$
Finally notice that $x_2-x_1=2\sqrt5$, $x_2+x_1=2a$ and that $x_2^2-x_1^2=(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)=4\sqrt5a$.